# Multilevel Moderated Mediation in b path

Tags: multilevel-analysis

currently I am dealing with the following problem:

I have a mediation model which I want to test in my multilevel data

```
X (=Stress)
Y (=Flow)
Mediator (=Stress-related behavior)
Moderator 1 (=Personality Factor 1)
Moderator 2 (=Personality Factor 2)
```

So my Hypothesis is that Flow (Y) occurs at a moderate stress level (X) and that this relationship is mediated via stress-related behavior (M). Further, I assume that the relationship between stress-related behavior and flow depends on 2 personality traits (=Moderators).

I am using mediation package in R to analyse data.

I am not quite sure, if I have specified the correct terms and maybe you can help me:

```
med.fit<-lmer(Mediator~X+I(X^2)+(1|VP01_01), data=MT3)
out.fit<-lmer(Flow~X+I(X^2)+Mediator*Trait1+Mediator*Trait2+(1|VP01_01), 
data=MT3)
med.out<-mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat="X", mediator= "Mediator", sims=100)
```

--> Right now, my code only specifies "X" and not "X" and "I(X^2)" as treat. How has the code has to look like so that quadratic effects are tested? 
--> Is the b-path moderation specified correctly?

Right now, I get this output, where it looks like that the mediation is not significant (ACME) but I'm not sure if I did it correclty:

```
Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value
ACME           -0.00676     -0.01988      0.00777    0.34
ADE            -0.10578     -0.18514     -0.02457    0.02
Total Effect   -0.11253     -0.18747     -0.03499    0.00
Prop. Mediated  0.06570     -0.05545      0.26450    0.34
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)